# Azure Devops CI for Azure Function failing to build. Strange compilation error

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions

Following this code:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-azure-devops?tabs=csharp%2Cwindows

the Build pipeline fail on the "script" task with this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C538B.png)

If I replace this:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: publish
    arguments: '--configuration Release --output publish_output'
    projects: '*.csproj'
    publishWebProjects: false
    modifyOutputPath: false
    zipAfterPublish: false
```

with this:

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
  solution: '***.sln'
  msbuildArgs: '/p:OutDir=$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output'

the build work but I need to publish
The project is built with Visual studio 2019 template for azure function. I did add an extra project to separate the logic, but it's all core 3.1. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

According to your screen shot :( the build is using .NET Core 2.2.401, which has already reached end of life and is not .NET Core 3.1 as you expect.

You need to add a [UseDotNet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops)  task to install the required .NET core release. Recommendation is that you have a `global.json` file for the version you expect.

```
      - task: UseDotNet@2
        displayName: 'Use .NET Core SDK (global.json)'
        inputs:
          packageType: 'sdk'
          useGlobalJson: true
```

For `useGlobalJson: false` you can specifiy the version which should be used explicitly.